# Mint 19.3. Can't connect to wifi

Tags: networking, linux-mint, wifi

I have downloaded  Mint 19.3 and am running it on an HP Stream 13. My wifi router is showing up in Networks  and seems to be connected. However, when I open a browser  (Firefox, then Chrome to see if there was any  difference) I just get the error message "Server  Not Found"?  If I connect my phone, thereby creating a wired connection, all works fine.

I cannot connect an ethernet cable because this is not an option on an HP Stream.

Answer (score 0):

Try pinging a network in the terminal with the `ping` command (such as google's DNS server 8.8.8.8) and see if you get a response. You can also run the command `ip addr` and see if you have been issued an IP address from the router. These are a few commands you can run to get a better understanding of the underlying issue of why you cannot connect to the internet. Please update on the results of these commands.

Comment: Tried ping  8.8.8.8 and got Network is unreachable.

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to copy the answer as requested, but heve exceeded the characters available!

Comment: And were you issued an IP address? (from the `ip addr` command)

Comment: I got 14  lines of script starting "!: lo LOOPBACK..." and ending "valid lift  forever  preferred lift  forever"  ?